# Problem Running Xgboost in Executable File

Tags: pyinstaller, xgboost

I am using a saved `Xgboost` model in a executable file created with `PyInstaller`.  I setup a virtual env and downloaded `Xgboost` and ensured it ran but after I create the exe and run the exe I get an error about `xgboost.core`:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module nemed 'xgboost.core'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I can't see any import problem with xgboost, first, make sure that you are using the latest version inside your env with `pip install -U xgboost` next try to add `xgboost.core` as a `hidden-import` and add xgboost's DLLs as `data-files`.

Suppose that your virtualenv is named `env`, use below command to generate your executable:

```
├───myscript.py
├───env
```

Code:

```
import traceback
try:
    from xgboost import core
    input("xgboost.core imported successfully!")
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
    input("Import Error!")
```

Command:

```
(env) > pyinstaller myscript.py -F --hidden-import=xgboost.core --add-data "./env/xgboost/*;xgboost/" 
--add-data "./env/Lib/site-packages/xgboost/VERSION;xgboost/"
```

Comment: Awesome! Using the --add-data worked like a charm!  Why is this needed?

Comment: Pyinstaller only handles module python directory, not the extra dependencies like DLLs, etc, so you need to feed them manually.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Masoud Rahimi did not work for me. What did was running pyinstaller using the `--collect-all` option:

```
pyinstaller -D <app_name>.py --noconfirm --collect-all "xgboost"
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4076) and the arguments in the [pyinstaller manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyinstaller.html)