# Error in running exe file having xgboost package by using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, xgboost

I have a code for predicting some value that uses `xgboost` package in the code. When I run it in PyCharm, it runs as expected.

The problem is when I make an executable file using `pyinstaller`. It will make the `exe` without any error, but when I run it the following error is raised:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test_fraud.py", line 3, in <module>
   import xgboost
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in 
   _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
   File 
  "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
  exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in 
  _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
  exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 161, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 123, in _load_lib
  File "lib\site-packages\xgboost\libpath.py", line 48, in find_lib_path
  xgboost.libpath.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in 
  the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root 
  path?
  List of candidates:
  C:\Users\SHUBHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11402\xgboost\xgboost.dll
  C:\Users\SHUBHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11402\xgboost
  \../../lib/xgboost.dll
 C:\Users\SHUBHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11402\xgboost\./lib/xgboost.dll
  C:\Users\SHUBHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11402\xgboost\xgboost.dll
 C:\Users\SHUBHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11402\xgboost
 \../../windows/x64/Release/xgboost.dll
   C:\Users\SHUBHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI11402\
  xgboost\./windows/x64/Release/xgboost.dll
 [6564] Failed to execute script test_fraud
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Pyinstaller can't find the `xgboost.dll`, `VERSION` files. So you need to add them manually to your output package. I also suggest you use a `try/except` block to see what is going on.
Suppose this simple example:

```
import traceback
try:
    import xgboost
    input("xgboost imported successfully!")
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
    input("Import Error!")
```

I suggest you use an [env](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20venv&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIR834IR834&oq=python%20venv&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.2093j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to build your script so, you need to add the `xgboost` directory located at `<path_to_venv>/xgboost` and `VERSION` file located at `<path_to_venv>/Lib/site-packages/xboost`. Next, add them as a data-file with pyinstaller. Launch your env and execute the below command (My virtualenv named as `env`):

```
├───myscript.py
├───env
```

Command:

```
(env) > pyinstaller myscript.py -F --add-data "./env/xgboost/*;xgboost/" --add-data "./env/Lib/site-packages/xgboost/VERSION;xgboost/"
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70532712/6627366

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with pyinstaller using 3.10 and trying to integrate xgboost. I downgraded my python version to 3.9.13, and ran this command line:

```
pyinstaller -F --collect-all "xgboost" your_script.py
```

and it worked.

It seems that pyinstaller is more stable with python 3.9 than 3.10 for this specific use case.