# error in running exe made by using pyinstaller having sklearn packages and xgboost

Tags: python-3.x, dll, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

i have made a exe file from a python file which have multiple import from our own files and have package sklearn, xgboost, pandas and other sklaern packages. during exe preparation thier is no error while running it it throw error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "probability_score_engine.py", line 16, in <module>
import sklearn.ensemble
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 16, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 21, in 
<module>
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 113, in 
<module>
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, 
in <module>
File "C:\Users\ShubhamSingh\PycharmProjects\cfna_scoring\venv\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in 
exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 10, 
in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[10668] Failed to execute script probability_score_engine
```

i have use add data for xgboost when it throw error in not finding dll files for xgboost but it throw error for sklearn. i have made a exe of one file but that file call other other python files function by using import.

Answer (score 0):

Both `sklearn` and `xgboost` needs special care when using with Pyinstaller. I'm skipping importing `xgboost` but here is a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493216/error-in-running-exe-file-having-xgboost-package-by-using-pyinstaller) about using it with Pyinstaller.

It seems that when you add `xgboost`Pyinstaller can't handle some modules like `scipy`. A simple approach is to add the whole `scipy` in Python's `sit-package` to your executable as data. So edit your spec file and add this after `Analysis`:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
datas=[('./env/xgboost/*', 'xgboost/'), ('./env/Lib/site-packages/xgboost/VERSION', 'xgboost/')],
    ...
)
# add here
a.datas += Tree('<path_to_scipy_in_python_dir>', prefix='scipy')
...
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

And finally, generate your executable with `pyinstaller script.spec`.

Comment: this not works for me, i have added 'a.datas += Tree('venv/Lib/site-packages/sklearn', prefix='sklearn')' this line after analysisi but got the same error

Comment: and now that error is not coming, another error occured                                  
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002430 (most recent call first):

Comment: You have many import modules which getting complicated. The `sklearn` and `xgboost` is ok now. Add your code to question and full error traceback.

Comment: `import os
    from datetime import datetime
    import xgboost
    import sklearn.ensemble
    import sklearn.tree
    import pickle
    import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
    import sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree
    import sklearn.tree._utils
    import cython
    import sklearn
    import sklearn.utils._cython_blas
    import numpy as np
    import joblib
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`

Comment: these are the imports that i have used

Comment: and error occured now `Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002430 (most recent call first):`

Comment: Look at edit. Create a new env. Use the above spec sample. It should fix your problem.

Comment: i have make new spec file including scipy data in it but it throw error                 
 `[1372] WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\SHUBHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI13722\scipy\optimize\moduleTNC.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000026c0 (most recent call first):`

Comment: The warning is because of adding `scipy` manually. I just imported all the modules you said and the above config would fix the problem. This error is related to your code thus I can't guess what is wrong.

Comment: please visit the above query provided as solution in this question @M. R.