# Can't add xgboost to pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, xgboost

My Python code involves `xgboost` library, and I now try to make exe using `pyinstaller`. The env is:

```
68 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0.dev0+8196c57ab
69 INFO: Python: 3.6.9 (conda)
70 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
```

I have tested running .py from command line in this env.

I located related files in the env: `dll`, `VERSION`, and the folder, and manually added them: (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493216/error-in-running-exe-file-having-xgboost-package-by-using-pyinstaller)) (I broke the command into new lines for readability)

```
(py36_PP) C:\Users\MarkZ\G_project\Model>pyinstaller PPP_2_main.py -F 
--add-data "C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\*;xgboost/" 
--add-data "C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\VERSION;xgboost/" 
--add-data "C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\Library\mingw-w64\bin\xgboost.dll;xgboost/"
```

How I found these paths:

1. import this library in python and see its attribute

   ```
   (py36_PP) C:\Users\MarkZ\GRS-PP-churn-project\Model>python
   Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 14:00:49) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import xgboost
   >>> print(xgboost.__file__)
   C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py
   ```
2. search:

   ```
   (base) C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3>dir /s *xgboost*
    Volume in drive C is OSDisk
    Volume Serial Number is F0FE-4464

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\conda-meta

   09/16/2019  01:58 PM            11,072 libxgboost-0.90-0.json
   09/16/2019  01:58 PM            11,048 py-xgboost-0.90-py37_0.json
   09/16/2019  01:58 PM             1,134 _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0.json
                  3 File(s)         23,254 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\conda-meta

   09/27/2019  01:45 AM            11,022 libxgboost-0.90-0.json
   09/27/2019  01:45 AM            10,998 py-xgboost-0.90-py36_0.json
   09/27/2019  01:45 AM             1,084 _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0.json
                  3 File(s)         23,104 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\Lib\site-packages

   09/27/2019  01:45 AM    <DIR>          xgboost
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\Library\mingw-w64\bin

   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         4,128,032 xgboost.dll
   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         4,218,018 xgboost.exe
                  2 File(s)      8,346,050 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\Library\mingw-w64\include

   09/27/2019  01:45 AM    <DIR>          xgboost
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\Library\mingw-w64\lib

   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         7,035,268 libxgboost.a
                  1 File(s)      7,035,268 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

   09/16/2019  01:58 PM    <DIR>          xgboost
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin

   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         4,128,032 xgboost.dll
   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         4,218,018 xgboost.exe
                  2 File(s)      8,346,050 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\include

   09/16/2019  01:58 PM    <DIR>          xgboost
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\lib

   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         7,035,268 libxgboost.a
                  1 File(s)      7,035,268 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs

   09/27/2019  01:45 AM    <DIR>          libxgboost-0.90-0
   09/16/2019  01:58 PM         1,913,797 libxgboost-0.90-0.conda
   09/27/2019  01:45 AM         4,050,208 libxgboost-0.90-0.tar.bz2
   09/27/2019  01:45 AM    <DIR>          py-xgboost-0.90-py36_0
   09/27/2019  01:45 AM            78,382 py-xgboost-0.90-py36_0.tar.bz2
   09/16/2019  01:58 PM    <DIR>          py-xgboost-0.90-py37_0
   09/16/2019  01:58 PM            76,618 py-xgboost-0.90-py37_0.conda
   09/27/2019  01:45 AM    <DIR>          _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0
   09/16/2019  01:58 PM             9,208 _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0.conda
   09/27/2019  01:45 AM             9,140 _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0.tar.bz2
                  6 File(s)      6,137,353 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libxgboost-0.90-0\info\recipe

   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               959 install-libxgboost.sh
                  1 File(s)            959 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libxgboost-0.90-0\info\recipe\parent

   06/06/2019  04:41 PM             2,814 0001-conda-Unbundle-libxgboost.-dll-dylib-so.patch
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               959 install-libxgboost.sh
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               159 install-py-xgboost.sh
   06/07/2019  02:06 PM               292 install-r-xgboost.sh
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               736 test-py-xgboost.py
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM             1,601 test-r-xgboost.r
                  6 File(s)          6,561 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libxgboost-0.90-0\Library\mingw-w64\bin

   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         4,128,032 xgboost.dll
   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         4,218,018 xgboost.exe
                  2 File(s)      8,346,050 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libxgboost-0.90-0\Library\mingw-w64\include

   09/27/2019  01:45 AM    <DIR>          xgboost
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libxgboost-0.90-0\Library\mingw-w64\lib

   06/07/2019  02:23 PM         7,035,268 libxgboost.a
                  1 File(s)      7,035,268 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\py-xgboost-0.90-py36_0\info\recipe

   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               159 install-py-xgboost.sh
                  1 File(s)            159 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\py-xgboost-0.90-py36_0\info\recipe\parent

   06/06/2019  04:41 PM             2,814 0001-conda-Unbundle-libxgboost.-dll-dylib-so.patch
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               959 install-libxgboost.sh
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               159 install-py-xgboost.sh
   06/07/2019  02:06 PM               292 install-r-xgboost.sh
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               736 test-py-xgboost.py
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM             1,601 test-r-xgboost.r
                  6 File(s)          6,561 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\py-xgboost-0.90-py36_0\Lib\site-packages

   09/27/2019  01:45 AM    <DIR>          xgboost
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\py-xgboost-0.90-py37_0\info\recipe

   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               159 install-py-xgboost.sh
                  1 File(s)            159 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\py-xgboost-0.90-py37_0\info\recipe\parent

   06/06/2019  04:41 PM             2,814 0001-conda-Unbundle-libxgboost.-dll-dylib-so.patch
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               959 install-libxgboost.sh
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               159 install-py-xgboost.sh
   06/07/2019  02:06 PM               292 install-r-xgboost.sh
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM               736 test-py-xgboost.py
   05/28/2019  11:57 AM             1,601 test-r-xgboost.r
                  6 File(s)          6,561 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\py-xgboost-0.90-py37_0\Lib\site-packages

   09/16/2019  01:58 PM    <DIR>          xgboost
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes

    Directory of C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\_py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0\info\recipe\parent

   06/28/2018  06:15 PM             2,500 0001-conda-Unbundle-libxgboost.-dll-dylib-so.patch
   06/28/2018  06:15 PM               959 install-libxgboost.sh
   06/28/2018  06:15 PM               159 install-py-xgboost.sh
   06/28/2018  06:15 PM               521 install-r-xgboost.sh
   06/28/2018  06:15 PM               736 test-py-xgboost.py
   06/28/2018  06:15 PM             1,601 test-r-xgboost.r
                  6 File(s)          6,476 bytes

        Total Files Listed:
                 48 File(s)     52,355,101 bytes
                 11 Dir(s)  34,365,415,424 bytes free
   ```

And it still can't load xgboost:

```
(py36_PP) C:\Users\MarkZ\G_project\Model>dist\PPP_2_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PPP_2_main.py", line 28, in <module>
    import xgboost as xgb
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\MarkZ\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_pp\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 621, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\MarkZ\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_pp\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 621, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 161, in <module>
  File "site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 123, in _load_lib
  File "site-packages\xgboost\libpath.py", line 52, in find_lib_path
xgboost.libpath.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
List of candidates:
C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI234002\Library\mingw-w64\bin\xgboost.dll
C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI234002\xgboost\../../windows/x64/Release/xgboost.dll
C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI234002\xgboost\./windows/x64/Release/xgboost.dll
[18264] Failed to execute script PPP_2_main
```

Looks like `pyinstaller` can't find `xgboost` - should I add path to `VERSION` file or `dll`?

Answer (score 1):

Both `VERSION` and `DLL` files are need for bundling the app. In a `virtualenv` the `xgboost` files are located in `<python_path>/xgboost` and the `VERSION` file is located in `<python_path>/Lib/site-packages/xgboost`.

So I think the command you need is:

```
(py36_PP) > pyinstaller myscript.py -F --add-data "C:/Users/MarkZ/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36_PP/xgboost/*;xgboost/" --add-data "C:/Users/MarkZ/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36_PP/Lib/site-packages/xgboost/VERSION;xgboost/"
```

Comment: thank you @M. R. - i don't have `<python_path>/xgboost` path  - see OP pls i updates all possible folders of `xgboost`

Comment: @YJZ the `<python_path>` is the path of where python is installed. In your case, it would be the path of environment e.g. `C:/Users/MarkZ/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36_PP`. I already replaced the path in the command. Have you tried that?

Comment: thank u so much for the prompt help @M. R.  - i don't have `/envs/py36_PP/xgboost/` either.... Could u take a look at OP `(2) search` please? It lists all possible folders. Maybe you can see which folder it should be... Appreciate your help.

Comment: @YJZ this path `C:\Users\MarkZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP` seems that your env where the python environment (`py36_PP`) is installed. Have you tried my command? `pyinstaller myscript.py -F --add-data "C:/Users/MarkZ/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36_PP/xgboost/*;xgboost/" --add-data "C:/Users/MarkZ/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36_PP/Lib/site-packages/xgboost/VERSION;xgboost/"`

Comment: Thank you- @M. R. Yes I tried. - it says `30885 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
Unable to find "C:\Users\zhayuji\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\xgboost\*" when adding binary and data files.`

Comment: On your console execute the `where python.exe` and paste the result in here. It seems that the xgboost path isn't correct.

Comment: thank u so much @M. R. -  `(py36_PP) C:\Users\zhayuji>where python.exe
C:\Users\zhayuji\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\python.exe
C:\Users\zhayuji\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe`

Comment: I'm still a little confused can you confirm this path is exists? `C:\Users\zhayuji\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\xgboost`

Comment: thank u @M. R.  - that folder does not exist. All folders under `anaconda3\envs\py36_PP\` are: conda-meta, 
DLLs, 
include, 
Lib, 
Library, 
libs, 
Scripts, 
tcl, 
Tools

Comment: Actually it should exist have you tried updating your conda and using `pip install -U xgboost`. The path should be there.

Comment: @MasoudRahimi I tried the exact solution, not working. I am still getting same error. I am using virtual env only.